# Issue Running NUnit Tests On Jenkins

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, mono, nunit, nunit-console

I have some small nunit tests written up for a Xamarin project. They run great on the terminal of my Mac Mini (jenkins build platform). When I run the same command on jenkins I'm getting a strange error that I cannot explain. I've tried provided full file paths and ran the command as root and I am still having this error thrown. If anyone has any experience with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Command for Build Process:

```
nuget restore CoreTests.sln
msbuild CoreTests.sln /t:Build
mono nunit3-console.exe CoreTests.dll
```

Error Output:

> NUnit Console Runner 3.7.0  Copyright (c) 2017 Charlie Poole, Rob
>   Prouse
>
> Runtime Environment    OS Version: MacOSX 16.6.0.0    CLR Version:
>   4.0.30319.42000
>
> Test Files
>       CoreTests/CoreTests/bin/Debug/CoreTests.dll
>
> Errors, Failures and Warnings
>
> 1) Error :  ApplicationName='mono', CommandLine='--runtime=v4.0.30319
>   "/Users/falconbot/Documents/NUnit/nunit-agent.exe"
>   8e81b5fe-8dba-4da0-8612-5c0cabe9d40f tcp://127.0.0.1:55001/TestAgency
>   --pid=97532', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x002dc] in
>   <70507a44a84041d599bbfa8f3d0ea5b1>:0    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in
>   <70507a44a84041d599bbfa8f3d0ea5b1>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()   at
>   NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.LaunchAgentProcess
>   (NUnit.Engine.TestPackage package) [0x002f2] in
>   <1e8ad6af4c6f4686ad7e5f9e67020b3b>:0    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.CreateRemoteAgent
>   (NUnit.Engine.TestPackage package, System.Int32 waitTime) [0x00000] in
>   <1e8ad6af4c6f4686ad7e5f9e67020b3b>:0    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency.GetAgent (NUnit.Engine.TestPackage
>   package, System.Int32 waitTime) [0x00000] in
>   <1e8ad6af4c6f4686ad7e5f9e67020b3b>:0    at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) NUnit.Engine.Services.TestAgency:GetAgent
>   (NUnit.Engine.TestPackage,int)   at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.CreateAgentAndRunner () [0x0003d]
>   in <1e8ad6af4c6f4686ad7e5f9e67020b3b>:0    at
>   NUnit.Engine.Runners.ProcessRunner.RunTests
>   (NUnit.Engine.ITestEventListener listener, NUnit.Engine.TestFilter
>   filter) [0x0001f] in <1e8ad6af4c6f4686ad7e5f9e67020b3b>:0
>
> Test Run Summary   Overall result: Failed   Test Count: 0, Passed: 0,
>   Failed: 0, Warnings: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Skipped: 0   Start time:
>   2017-09-28 18:18:49Z
>       End time: 2017-09-28 18:18:49Z
>       Duration: 0.089 seconds
>
> Results (nunit3) saved as TestResult.xml Build step 'Execute shell'
>   marked build as failure

Comment: Are you copying nunit3-console.exe somewhere manually? It looks like the console can't locate nunit-agent.exe, which should be sat in the same directory.

Comment: I shortened the command for the sake of the post. It's store in a directory called NUnit that also contains nunit-agent.exe and the full file path to nunit3-console.exe is used when I call it in jenkins.

Comment: maybe posting the full debug output from Jenkins could help, and a look at your configuration in more detail

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are getting to the third line without error I would suggest it should be:

```
nunit3-console.exe <workspace_relative_path_to_project_containing_tests>.dll
```

Disclaimer: I am contributor to the NUnit project and author of the [Saucery3](http://nuget.org/packages/saucery3) nuget package.  But I am not a mono expert.

Comment: Yea I am aware that I can run the unit tests with the dll that is built. I get the same results when I try to run the unit tests from the dll from within Jenkins but works fine when I run from the command line myself.

Comment: You should be executing nunit3-console.exe from a Windows Batch Step as part of the build. nunit3-console.exe either needs to be in your %PATH% or provided the full c:\ rooted path to nunit3-console.exe in the Windows Batch step.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem when I tried run NUnit-console (using Mono on MacOS)  over an SSH connection. In my case executing `source /etc/profile;` command before running it resolved the problem.

```
ssh user@host source /etc/profile; {MonoPath}/mono {NUnitPath}/nunit3-console.exe {TestsPath}/Test.dll
```